# How do I work out who is the youngest in list of drivers

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

I need to be able to calculate the youngest driver and then apply a policy change amount to its value ie if there between a certain age bracket.

```
public void UpdatePolicyPremium(int policyid,Decimal amount)
    {

        List<tblDriver> driver = appliedDB.tblDrivers.Where(b => b.policy_Id == policyid).ToList();
        foreach (var drivers in driver)
        {
         if (drivers.age >21 && drivers.age <25) i should increase by 20% if youngest driver
            {

                tblPolicy _policy = appliedDB.tblPolicies.Where(b => b.id ==  policyid).SingleOrDefault();

                _policy.amount = _policy.amount + amount;
            }

            if (drivers.age > 26 && drivers.age < 75)// i should increase by 10 percent if youngest driver
            {

                tblPolicy _policy = appliedDB.tblPolicies.Where(b => b.id == policyid).SingleOrDefault();

                _policy.amount = _policy.amount + amount;
            }
        }

        appliedDB.SaveChanges();

    }
```

But the procedure has to figure out who is the yongest driver within that bracket and I am not sure how I would go about that

Tables

Driver Table
ID
First Name 
Last Name 
DOB 
Age

Policy Table
ID
Driver ID
Start Date
Amount
isIncreaseOnPolicy

Re Post
   I have tried the option by Gert Arnold which does appear to work but I also need the added functionallity of start date of the policy

This is the task

•   If the youngest driver is aged between 21 and 25 at the start date of the policy increase the premium by 20%

Ie BaseAmount =500 so an increase of 10 % would be 50 pounds that should be added on if they are aged between 21 and 25 at the start date

Comment: Store a variable for each age bracket, check it in each loop iteration against what is stored already and replace the value if it's "younger" than what is already stored.

Comment: First of all you need => and <= instead of > and  <, also your amount parameter is useless

Comment: @AntoinePelletier how is it useless when u dont no wha tthe function is behind applied I was only asked to go for those gorups

Comment: And now you introduce a start date. What's next? I suggest you remove the latest edits form your question and show by sample data what you want. This is utterly unclear.

Comment: I have done what you ask and removed the edits and placed what i want as result

Answer (score 2):

Order the drivers by the age and get the first driver. This driver will be the youngest of the bunch. Code as bellow (have not compilled it)

```
public void UpdatePolicyPremium(int policyid, Decimal amount)
{
   tblDriver driver = appliedDB.tblDrivers.Where(b => b.policy_Id == policyid).OrderBy(r =>r.Age).FirstOrDefault();
   if (driver != null)
   {
      if (driver.age > 21 && driver.age < 25) //i should increase by 20 % if youngest driver
      {
         tblPolicy _policy = appliedDB.tblPolicies.Where(b => b.id == policyid).SingleOrDefault();
         _policy.amount = _policy.amount * 1.2;
      }

      if (driver.age > 26 && driver.age < 75)// i should increase by 10 percent if youngest driver
      {
         tblPolicy _policy = appliedDB.tblPolicies.Where(b => b.id == policyid).SingleOrDefault();
         _policy.amount = _policy.amount * 1.1;
      }
   }
   appliedDB.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: I need to be able to arrange this by also the start dayte of the policy the policy table has a start date the rule is written above in the new edit ?

Comment: How would I add the requirment of the start date to this please