# How do i apply a date range to the policy

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am working on this proecdure to allow for the table will have the following

> Policy Table ID START DATE END DATE AGE Amount
>
> If the youngest driver is aged between 21 and 25 at the start date
> of the policy increase the premium by 20%
>
> If the youngest driver is  aged between 26 and 75 at the start date of the policy decrease the premium by 10%

I beleive i have managed the yougest driver and the age range but I do not no how to acheve the creatiea at the start date of the policy.

The customers policy will have a default value of £500 applied to it

```
public void UpdatePolicyAgePremium(int policyid)
    {
    Decimal defaultAmount = Convert.ToDecimal(500);
    var drivergroups = appliedDB.tblDrivers
      .Where(b => b.policy_Id == policyid && b.age > 21 && b.age < 75)
      .GroupBy(drv => drv.age <= 25).ToList(); // or < 25 ?

    var policy = appliedDB.tblPolicies
                          .Single(p => p.id == policyid);

    foreach (var driverGroup in drivergroups)
    {
        var young = driverGroup.Key;
        decimal multiplier = young ? 1.2m : 1.1m;
        foreach (var driver in driverGroup.OrderBy(d => d.age))
        {
            policy.amount = defaultAmount * multiplier;
            multiplier = 1m; // so only the first iteration is multiplied.
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: Instead of age, store birthday (calculate age) and you can compare it with the start date. Roughly age at startdate is  startdate - birthdate

Comment: how would i compare it @DanHunex

Comment: You don't need to compare. You calculate the age at the start date. Age = StartDate - Birthdate ,  then apply you rule of 21 to 26 or 26 to 74. The calculation will take into consideration the start date

Comment: Looks [familiar](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42633285/861716) and it's still absolutely unclear what you want. Why don't you follow up on my earlier advice to show sample data and results?

Answer (score 0):

Store birtdate and just calculate the age of the person at the start date and then apply the age rule. You can calculate the age something like

```
  //assuming start date is now, but //depends on your implementation
    DateTime startDate = DateTime.Now   ;

    var age = today.Year - birthdate.Year;
```

Then you have the age to apply your rule

Comment: Sorry dan i should have ben more percise i ment with the age the way i have the to check the various age groups and that was not my orignal quesiton how would i compare with the start date of the policy